# Lighttpd: Expose files in a directory only through chosen URL pattern

Tags: web-server, http, lighttpd

## Background

I have a web page `X`, which I would like to serve through only through URLs matching `/X/${UUID}`, where `UUID` is a random UUID which I give to a person. I have come up with a solution which involves creating symbolic links from directory outside of the web root to a directory with name `${UUID}$` inside the web root.

## Approximate Solution

1. Define `WEB=/Users/jpcooper/Web`.
2. `mkdir $WEB/internal`
3. `mv index.html style.css script.js $WEB`.
4. `mkdir -p $WEB/root/X`.
5. `cd $WEB/root/X; ln -s ../../internal ${UUID}`.

`lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.document-root = "${WEB}/root"
server.follow-symlink = "enable"
index-file.names = ( "index.html" )
mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html",
  ".css" => "text/css",
  ".js" => "text/javascript"
)
```

Lighttpd will now expose only the urls of the form `/X/${UUID}`.

## Improvement?

Is there any better way of registering UUIDs somewhere and having URLs of the form `/X/${UUID}` proxied to the `${WEB}/internal` directory? Can this be done without CGI?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at lighttpd mod_secdownload? https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSecDownload